# Nodemon in ApostropheCMS not working

Tags: apostrophe-cms

This is my output after launching nodemon. I also have the latest nodemon config after create-project using apostrophe-cli . I tried many solutions online but none of them fixed it. Somehow errors on nodemon config or in windows system itself . I also did running nodemon in administrator console.

```
[nodemon] 1.18.3
[nodemon] reading config .\package.json[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] or send SIGHUP to 10964 to restart[nodemon] ignoring: locales/*.json public/modules/**/*.less public/modules/**/*.js .\public\uploads/**/* public/apos-minified/*.js public/css/master-*.less .\data/**/*
[nodemon] watching: *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: json,js,html,less
[nodemon] starting `node app.js`
[nodemon] forking
[nodemon] child pid: 13600
[nodemon] watching 1164 files
apostrophe-profiler: APOS_PROFILER environment variable not set, doing nothing.
C:\Users\Alienware\Desktop\amin-website\node_modules\rimraf\rimraf.js:313
        throw er
        ^

Error: ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rmdir 'C:\Users\Alienware\Desktop\amin-website\public\modules\apostrophe-assets\js'
    at Object.fs.rmdirSync (fs.js:870:18)
    at rmkidsSync (C:\Users\Alienware\Desktop\amin-website\node_modules\rimraf\rimraf.js:356:25)
    at rmdirSync (C:\Users\Alienware\Desktop\amin-website\node_modules\rimraf\rimraf.js:334:7)
    at rimrafSync (C:\Users\Alienware\Desktop\amin-website\node_modules\rimraf\rimraf.js:304:9)
    at C:\Users\Alienware\Desktop\amin-website\node_modules\rimraf\rimraf.js:342:5
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at rmkidsSync (C:\Users\Alienware\Desktop\amin-website\node_modules\rimraf\rimraf.js:341:26)
    at rmdirSync (C:\Users\Alienware\Desktop\amin-website\node_modules\rimraf\rimraf.js:334:7)
    at Function.rimrafSync [as sync] (C:\Users\Alienware\Desktop\amin-website\node_modules\rimraf\rimraf.js:304:9)
    at Object.self.removeThenRecursiveCopy (C:\Users\Alienware\Desktop\amin-website\node_modules\apostrophe\lib\modules\apostrophe-assets\index.js:690:18)
    at Object.self.linkAssetFolderOnWindows (C:\Users\Alienware\Desktop\amin-website\node_modules\apostrophe\lib\modules\apostrophe-assets\index.js:673:19)
    at Object.self.linkAssetFolder (C:\Users\Alienware\Desktop\amin-website\node_modules\apostrophe\lib\modules\apostrophe-assets\index.js:628:14)
    at C:\Users\Alienware\Desktop\amin-website\node_modules\apostrophe\lib\modules\apostrophe-assets\index.js:596:14
    at C:\Users\Alienware\Desktop\amin-website\node_modules\@sailshq\lodash\lib\index.js:3253:15
    at baseForOwn (C:\Users\Alienware\Desktop\amin-website\node_modules\@sailshq\lodash\lib\index.js:2223:14)
    at C:\Users\Alienware\Desktop\amin-website\node_modules\@sailshq\lodash\lib\index.js:3223:18
```

When running nodemon again , it came out on different error :

```
[nodemon] 1.18.3
[nodemon] reading config .\package.json[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] or send SIGHUP to 21852 to restart[nodemon] ignoring: locales/*.json public/modules/**/*.less public/modules/**/*.js .\public\uploads/**/* public/apos-minified/*.js public/css/master-*.less .\data/**/*
[nodemon] watching: *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: json,js,html,less
[nodemon] starting `node app.js`
[nodemon] forking
[nodemon] child pid: 26028
[nodemon] watching 1330 files
apostrophe-profiler: APOS_PROFILER environment variable not set, doing nothing.
fs.js:909
  return binding.mkdir(pathModule.toNamespacedPath(path),
                 ^
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Users\Alienware\Desktop\amin-website\public\modules\apostrophe-admin-bar'
    at Object.fs.mkdirSync (fs.js:909:18)
    at copyDir (C:\Users\Alienware\Desktop\amin-website\node_modules\apostrophe\lib\modules\apostrophe-assets\index.js:709:14)
    at Object.self.recursiveCopy (C:\Users\Alienware\Desktop\amin-website\node_modules\apostrophe\lib\modules\apostrophe-assets\index.js:705:7)
    at Object.self.removeThenRecursiveCopy (C:\Users\Alienware\Desktop\amin-website\node_modules\apostrophe\lib\modules\apostrophe-assets\index.js:693:12)    at Object.self.linkAssetFolderOnWindows (C:\Users\Alienware\Desktop\amin-website\node_modules\apostrophe\lib\modules\apostrophe-assets\index.js:673:19)
    at Object.self.linkAssetFolder (C:\Users\Alienware\Desktop\amin-website\node_modules\apostrophe\lib\modules\apostrophe-assets\index.js:628:14)
    at C:\Users\Alienware\Desktop\amin-website\node_modules\apostrophe\lib\modules\apostrophe-assets\index.js:596:14
    at C:\Users\Alienware\Desktop\amin-website\node_modules\@sailshq\lodash\lib\index.js:3253:15
    at baseForOwn (C:\Users\Alienware\Desktop\amin-website\node_modules\@sailshq\lodash\lib\index.js:2223:14)
    at C:\Users\Alienware\Desktop\amin-website\node_modules\@sailshq\lodash\lib\index.js:3223:18
    at Function.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Alienware\Desktop\amin-website\node_modules\@sailshq\lodash\lib\index.js:3526:13)
    at self.symlinkModules (C:\Users\Alienware\Desktop\amin-website\node_modules\apostrophe\lib\modules\apostrophe-assets\index.js:592:9)
    at C:\Users\Alienware\Desktop\amin-website\node_modules\apostrophe\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:718:13
    at iterate (C:\Users\Alienware\Desktop\amin-website\node_modules\apostrophe\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:262:13)
    at async.forEachOfSeries.async.eachOfSeries (C:\Users\Alienware\Desktop\amin-website\node_modules\apostrophe\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:281:9)
    at _parallel (C:\Users\Alienware\Desktop\amin-website\node_modules\apostrophe\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:717:9)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Running nodemon again , this error came out :

```
Error: ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rmdir 'C:\Users\Alienware\Desktop\amin-website\public\modules\apostrophe-notifications\css'
at Object.fs.rmdirSync (fs.js:870:18)
at rmkidsSync (C:\Users\Alienware\Desktop\amin-website\node_modules\rimraf\rimraf.js:356:25)
at rmdirSync (C:\Users\Alienware\Desktop\amin-website\node_modules\rimraf\rimraf.js:334:7)
at rimrafSync (C:\Users\Alienware\Desktop\amin-website\node_modules\rimraf\rimraf.js:304:9)
at C:\Users\Alienware\Desktop\amin-website\node_modules\rimraf\rimraf.js:342:5
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at rmkidsSync (C:\Users\Alienware\Desktop\amin-website\node_modules\rimraf\rimraf.js:341:26)
at rmdirSync (C:\Users\Alienware\Desktop\amin-website\node_modules\rimraf\rimraf.js:334:7)
at Function.rimrafSync [as sync] (C:\Users\Alienware\Desktop\amin-website\node_modules\rimraf\rimraf.js:304:9)
at Object.self.removeThenRecursiveCopy (C:\Users\Alienware\Desktop\amin-website\node_modules\apostrophe\lib\modules\apostrophe-assets\index.js:690:18)
at Object.self.linkAssetFolderOnWindows (C:\Users\Alienware\Desktop\amin-website\node_modules\apostrophe\lib\modules\apostrophe-assets\index.js:673:19)
at Object.self.linkAssetFolder (C:\Users\Alienware\Desktop\amin-website\node_modules\apostrophe\lib\modules\apostrophe-assets\index.js:628:14)
at C:\Users\Alienware\Desktop\amin-website\node_modules\apostrophe\lib\modules\apostrophe-assets\index.js:596:14
at C:\Users\Alienware\Desktop\amin-website\node_modules\@sailshq\lodash\lib\index.js:3253:15
at baseForOwn (C:\Users\Alienware\Desktop\amin-website\node_modules\@sailshq\lodash\lib\index.js:2223:14)
at C:\Users\Alienware\Desktop\amin-website\node_modules\@sailshq\lodash\lib\index.js:3223:18
```

And also running some other time again , on my visual studio code output came out like this :

```
    [Error - 1:27:44 AM] (node:17664) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'c:\Users\Alienware\Desktop\amin-website\public\modules\apostrophe-assets\css\vendor\cropper.less'
[Error - 1:27:52 AM] (node:17664) DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
[Error - 1:27:56 AM] (node:17664) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 2): Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'c:\Users\Alienware\Desktop\amin-website\public\modules\apostrophe-assets\css\vendor\jquery-ui-3.less'
[Error - 1:27:59 AM] (node:17664) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 3): Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'c:\Users\Alienware\Desktop\amin-website\public\modules\apostrophe-assets\css\vendor\jquery-ui.less'
[Error - 1:28:01 AM] (node:17664) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 4): Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'c:\Users\Alienware\Desktop\amin-website\public\modules\apostrophe-assets\css\vendor\pikaday.less'
[Error - 1:28:03 AM] (node:17664) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 5): Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'c:\Users\Alienware\Desktop\amin-website\public\modules\apostrophe-assets\css\vendor\spectrum.less'
[Error - 1:28:22 AM] (node:17664) PromiseRejectionHandledWarning: Promise rejection was handled asynchronously (rejection id: 1)
[Error - 1:28:23 AM] (node:17664) PromiseRejectionHandledWarning: Promise rejection was handled asynchronously (rejection id: 2)
[Error - 1:28:23 AM] (node:17664) PromiseRejectionHandledWarning: Promise rejection was handled asynchronously (rejection id: 3)
[Error - 1:28:24 AM] (node:17664) PromiseRejectionHandledWarning: Promise rejection was handled asynchronously (rejection id: 4)
[Error - 1:28:26 AM] (node:17664) PromiseRejectionHandledWarning: Promise rejection was handled asynchronously (rejection id: 5)
```

Comment: Is it possible you ran something previously as Administrator? You should never have to run anything Apostrophe-related as Administrator, but if you do the files might not be writable by your normal user afterwards.

Comment: Before it all happens , I running the console without as Administrator . When this error happened , I started to look on online solution including Stack Overflow question . None of them fix ! Some of the solution I tried , is to use as Admin Console running Nodemon . So to answer your question , I did not run as Admin when everything was fine without this kind of error.

Comment: What is in this folder after the error occurs? (Replace with the appropriate path if you get a different error next time.)

`C:\Users\Alienware\Desktop\amin-website\public\modules\apostrophe-assets\js`

(Edited with correct path, sorry about that off-topic screenshot)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had these kind of issues until i found the following post on apostrophe forum

http://forum.apostrophecms.org/t/nodemon-instead-of-node/458

The solution is change your package.json and modify the nodemon section and make sure it has the "watch" parameter as follows

"nodemonConfig": {
  "verbose": true,
  "watch": ["app.js", "lib/modules"]
}

I hope this helps

Comment: OMG , this one FIX NODEMON ERRORS ! WONDERFUL SOLUTION ! Hope everyone will find this issue and fix their problem using nodemon easily especially for windows users. It probably because this nodemon config is incomplete when create project using apostrophe cli. THANKS MAN !

Comment: I am glad that it helped you Amin